# Is there a way to create Graphics from BitmapData?

Tags: c#, graphics, gdi+, bitmapdata

I'm using *BitmapData* to perform various drawing on it.
Now i'm looking to draw some text.
Because i would like to avoid the complexity of implementing the string fonts to pixels transformation I would like to use the available *DrawString* method on graphics object.

So I'm looking for a way to create a Graphic object working on a device that will be my *BitmapData*.

I saw there is a *Graphics.FromHdc* method available. But when i use it with the *Scan0* of my *BitmapData* it throws a *System.OutOfMemoryException*.

Comment: You can use [Graphics.FromImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage.aspx).

Comment: How do you create the BitmapData? Can't you create it from a Bitmap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually a `BitmapData` object is derived from an existing `Bitmap` like this:

```
Bitmap bmp = // insert some way to create your bitmap!
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size);

BitmapData BD =  bmp.LockBits(rect , ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,  bmp.PixelFormat);
//  
//  do your pixel stuff here
//
bmp.UnlockBits(BD);

using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp) )
{
    //
    // do your Graphics stuff here
    // 
}
```